# Javascript activeElement doesen't work for dynamically created text-fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create dynamically text fields when some text is entered to the text field. At first it created new textfield after every keystroke, but i tried to narrow it down so it would create one text-field per text-field.

To explain with a brief example, what i want to get is that in the beginning i have textfield A. If something is typed in textfield A then textfield B is created under textfield A. If something is typed in textfield B then textfield C is created under textfield B, and so on until the user leaves the last one empty.

What's wrong is the activeElement does not get chosen for dynamically created element. My idea was that when another textfield gets selected it will become (should've become) an activeElement with a length of a zero thus changing createNew to true and allowing it to create new textfield.

I hope i explained clearly what i'm trying to achieve, but English is not my mother-tongue so it's a bit difficult. I may be approaching this problem with a bad perspective so if someone has a better idea how to create text fields dynamically i'm open to different options. I did some googling before and didn't find much about that particular idea.

Anyways, here's my js.

```
//This is the javascript for the namepage.html
var createNew = true;

function getNewInsertion() {
    var container = document.getElementById("inputcontainer");

    if (document.activeElement.value.length == 0 && createNew == false){
        createNew = true;
    }
    else if (createNew == true){
        createNew = false;
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = "text";
        input.className = "form-control text-controller"; // set the CSS class
        input.placeholder = "Sisesta siia nimi";
        container.appendChild(input);
    }

    return createNew;
}



$(function() {
    $(".text-controller").bind("paste cut keydown",function(e) {
        getNewInsertion();

    })

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should [delegate the event](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) on the container:

```
$(function() {
    $("#inputcontainer").on( "paste cut keydown", "input", function(e) {
        getNewInsertion();
    })
});
```

Here I leave you a snippet:

```js
var createNew = true;

function getNewInsertion() {
    var container = document.getElementById("inputcontainer");

  if (document.activeElement.value.length == 0 && createNew == false){
        createNew = true;
    }
    else if (createNew == true){
        createNew = false;
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = "text";
        input.className = "form-control text-controller"; // set the CSS class
        input.placeholder = "Sisesta siia nimi";
        container.appendChild(input);
    }

    return createNew;
}

$(function() {
    $("#inputcontainer").on( "paste cut keydown", "input", function(e) {
        getNewInsertion();
    })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="inputcontainer">
  <input type="text" class="text-controller" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you David, didn't expect it to be so simple!

Comment: @Banana: Glad it helped :)